# CSS not showing correctly in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am having issues with certain styles not showing correctly in browsers for tables that I created. Specifically the class I created .rowB background color not showing as well as the right side border that I created for class cellBrdrRght.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* info charts */
td{ 
vertical-align: middle;
}
.chartHeader{
background-color: #115967!important;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}
.rowA{
background-color: #d0d0d0!important;
color: #4b4b4b;
    
.rowB{
background-color: #666666!important;
color: #fff;
}
.cellBrdrRght {
border-style: solid!important;
border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px!important;
border-color: white!important;
}
.cellnoBrd {
border-style: none;
}
.tableFooter{
font-size: 10px;
border-style: none;
background-color: #115967!important;
color: #fff;
text-align: left;
colspan: 3;
a:sideBar {
background-color: #115967!important;
padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://benefitsatbenefitelect.com/new/wp-content/styles/other-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="chartHeader">
<td class="cellBrdrRght">Plan Benefits</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd" colspan="2">Current Benefits</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowA">
<td class="cellBrdrRght">Description</td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">PPO</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">HDHP</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowB">
<td class="cellBrdrRght" style="text-align:left;"><b>Deductible</b> In/Out-of-Network &amp; 2x Family</td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">$1,250/$2,250**</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">$3,000/$6,000**</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowA">
<td class="cellBrdrRght" style="text-align:left;"><b>Coinsurance</b> In/Out-of-Network</td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">Alaska Plan 20%/20%<br> Non-Alaska Plan 20%/40%</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">Alaska Plan 20%/20%<br> Non-Alaska Plan 20%/40%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowB">
<td class="cellBrdrRght" style="text-align:left;"><b>Out-of-Pocket Maximum</b> In/Out-of-Network &amp; 2x Family</td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">$5,000/$10,000</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">$5,000/$10,000</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowA">
<td class="cellBrdrRght" style="text-align:left;"><b>Primary/Specialist Office</b></td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">$30 PCP/$40 Specialist</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">Alaska Plan*: PCP 20%/20% Specialist 20%/20%<br> Non-Alaska Plan*: PCP 20%/40% Specialist 20%/40%</td>
</tr>
<tr class="rowB">
<td class="cellBrdrRght" style="text-align:left;"><b>Retail Prescriptions</b>Generic/Preferred/Non-Preferred</td>
<td class="cellBrdrRght">$20/$45/$60</td>
<td class="cellnoBrd">20%*</td>
</tr>
<tr class="tableFooter">
<td colspan="3">*After Deductible is met **Individuals in Family Tier need only meet individual deductible vs. family deductible</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<hr/>
</div>
```

web page:
http://benefitsatbenefitelect.com/new/index.php/portfolio-item/dark-places/

css file:
http://benefitsatbenefitelect.com/new/wp-content/styles/other-styles.css

Comment: paste your code here... it will be greatful.

Comment: Please edit your orginal post to include the code you put in your comments, and additionally explain why/what the direct problem and result is

Comment: You are missing a lot of stuff in your HTML; maybe it is just transcription error when you posted it in the comments, but you should double check for typos and then run your code through an HTML validator first before coming here to ask about it.

Comment: @user9876931 your .rowA is not properly closed in {}. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* info charts */

td{ 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.chartHeader{
    background-color: #115967 !important;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.rowA{
    background-color: #d0d0d0 !important;
    color: #4b4b4b;
}
.rowB{
    background-color: #666666 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
.cellBrdrRght {
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px !important;
    border-color: white !important;
}
.cellnoBrd {
    border-style: none;
}
.tableFooter{
    font-size: 10px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: #115967 !important;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    colspan: 3;
}
a:sideBar {
    background-color: #115967 !important;
    padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Change this your .rowA & .tableFooter is not closed properly in {}...

Comment: thank you very much, I guess I was just staring at it too long, should of taken a step back and looked again.

Answer (score 0):

You missed closing tags in .rowA:

```
.rowA{
  background-color: #d0d0d0!important;
  color: #4b4b4b;
}
```

and in .tableFooter:

```
.tableFooter{
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: #115967!important;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  colspan: 3;
  }
```

Try this and it should properly work